# Redirect stdout to multiple programs

Tags: bash, shell, pipe

I'm doing some stream processing of some quite substantial files-- I was wondering if there was a way to split stdout in order to pipe to multiple programs. What I'd like to do is something like this:

```
bzcat some_huge_file.bz2 | (wc > wordcount, char_stats > character_statistics)
```

I could write this glue in something like perl or python, but it seems like there ought to be a way to do this.

Google brings me to [`tpipe`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tpipe), but I can't find any copy of tpipe or sources (nothing local on OS X 10.8).

Comment: Found it- I don't have enough rep to post the answer outside a comment:


The answer is `tee` and ["process substitution"](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/tee-invocation.html). 

    bzcat some_huge_file.bz2 | tee >(wc > wordcount) |  char_stats > character_statistics

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Converting the poster's comment into a formal answer:

The answer is tee and "process substitution".

**Example**

```
bzcat some_huge_file.bz2 | tee >(wc > wordcount) | char_stats > character_statistics
```

Comment: It does however seem, that at least on OS X Lion, this results in some gently unexpected results-- Specifically, from what I've seen, it appears that the output of the process-substituted command (`wc` above) gets mixed with the input into the last command there (`char_stats` above)